# Сохранение выбранных значений в поле в Select2

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, select2

Всем привет!
Я использую плагин Select2 для выбора значений. 
Я выбираю значения, они красиво вставляются в input.
Но при отправке формы я перехожу на другую страницу и у меня должна быть возможность вернуть на страницу с выбором из select с сохранением заполненных мной полей.
Они как бы выбраны, но почему-то не отображаются в инпуте.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И если выбрать какое-то поле, то и прошлые отобразятся сразу же, и новые
Вот, например, если выбрать третье значение, то и 2 прошлых тоже отобразятся
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при возврате страницы, сразу же отображались введенные раннее значения в инпутах?

```
<select id="e20" name="know[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option data-badge="">Систематизировать</option>
    <option data-badge="">Собирать</option>
    <option data-badge="">Определить</option>
    <option data-badge="">Описать</option>
  </select>

<script>
     $("#e20").select2({
      tags:[],
      tokenSeparators: [",", " "]});
</script>
```

Вот начало формы

```
 <form method="POST" action="upload1.php" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneFrom" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

То есть при нажатии переходим на upload1.php и нужно, чтобы при возвращении на index.php сохранялись значения в input.

Реализация input в JS

```
Search.prototype.render = function (decorated) {
var $search = $(
'<li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">' +
'<input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="-1"' +
' autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none"' +
' spellcheck="false" role="searchbox" aria-autocomplete="list" />' +
'</li>'
);
```

Comment: навесьте на onload страницы то же событие, что происходит на onChange селекта. Тут явно такое творится: ,пПри возврате на страницу селект сохраняет свое значение (выбранные элементы), а вставка их в инпут не происходит, т.к. нет события onChange. Но как только оно происходит (вы выбираете еще одно поле), оно добавляется к уже сохраненным и срабатывает onChange, отчего в инпут пропихиваются и прошлые ,и новые.

Comment: @Gama Приложите в вопрос Ваш код.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, приложил

Comment: @Инквизитор, может быть Вы знаете, как это сделать с помощью свойств плагина?

Comment: @Gama можно сделать на чистом php без `jquery`.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, не подскажите как??

Comment: @Gama, Да, сейчас подготовлю пример, только подскажите, какие действия выполняете в файле `upload1.php` и как возвращаете на предыдущую страницу. По клику или просто кнопка "назад" в браузере?

Comment: @Denis640Kb, в файле у меня идет строковые преобразования всех элементов интупов, запись их в БД и вывод преобразованных строк. Просто кнопка "назад" в браузере

Answer (score 0):

Первый файл:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['select'])){
    $val1 = $_COOKIE['select']; // Получаем куки, если он есть.
    $val = json_decode($val1); // Преобразуем в массив.
}  else {
    $val = []; // Если куки нет, то пустой массив.
}
print_r($val); // Это для демонстации сохранения данных при возврате (После теста удалите).
?>

<form method="POST" action="upload1.php" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneFrom" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select id="e20" name="know[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option data-badge="" <?php if(in_array('Систематизировать', $val)){ echo "selected";}?>>Систематизировать</option>
        <option data-badge="" <?php if(in_array('Собирать', $val)){ echo "selected";}?>>Собирать</option>
        <option data-badge="" <?php if(in_array('Определить', $val)){ echo "selected";}?>>Определить</option>
        <option data-badge="" <?php if(in_array('Описать', $val)){ echo "selected";}?>>Описать</option>
    </select>
    <button formmethod="post">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Второй файл - `upload.php`

```php
if(isset($_POST['know'])){ //Получаем данные селекта
    $val1 = $_POST['know']; // Сохраняем в переменную
    $val = json_encode($val1); // Кодируем массив в строку
    setcookie("select", $val); // Сохраняем в куки.
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, но я протестировал ваш метод, и ничего не изменилось. Значения все равно отображаются только в раскрывающемся списке, но не инпуте

Comment: @Gama Так у Вас же нет поля `input` по крайней мере в примере - если надо могу добавить.

Comment: ой, не инпут, а вот это поле для ввода значений

Comment: @Gama Или добавьте тогда `css` и разметку `html`, где вы реализовали поле ввода.

Comment: @Gama селект не может содержать строковое значение. На то он и селект. У Вас это организовано через поле инпут. Добавьте Вашу `css` и разметку `html`, чтобы видно было, как Вы его реализуете.

Comment: поля ввода реализованы с помощью плагина select2. Там достаточно много css кода. Но я думаю, что input организован через js. Я добавил кусок js кода в вопрос

Comment: я могу дать ссылку на сайт, если это поможет

Comment: @Gama, давайте.

Comment: <http://p96437mh.beget.tech/>